# Kafka Connection handling

Tags: error-handling, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am consuming data from `kafka` with the `createDirectStream()` API. I would like to `catch` `ClosedChannelException` and handle disconnection to `zookeeper` and kafka topics.

Through tests, I was only able to do this:

```
try { myStreamingContext.awaitTermination }
catch { case foo:SparkException => if (foo.getMessage contains """ClosedChannelException""") /*do something*/ }
```

It appears the exception is only "catchable" with the above, or at least, not with `try { val stream = createDirectStream([...]) } [...]` as I expected.

Is there any method to handle this (and other connection errors) application-side?